# How to create an UniqueValidator on multiple fields inside FlaskForm

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a `FlaskForm` called `AddStudentForm` which goes like this:

```
class AddStudentForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=24)])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=24)])
    dob = DateField('Date of Birth', format='%d/%m/%Y', validators=[DataRequired()])
    cls = SelectField('Class', choices=[(member.value, name) for name, member in Level.__members__.items()])
    sec = SelectField('Section', choices=[('A', 'SEC-A'), ('B', 'SEC-B'), ('C', 'SEC-C')])
    roll = IntegerField('Roll Number', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=400)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

I want to validate both cls (short for class) and roll fields together so that combination of these 2 fields remain unique. On single field like **`email`** I can do this easily, **but how can I do this on multiple fields?**

My associated codes are as follows (for ref.):

**Unique email validator inside `AddStudentForm` (I want something like this for multiple fields together)**

```
def validate_email(self, email):
    stud = Student.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
    if stud:
        raise ValidationError('A student is already exists with same email! Please change your email.')
```

**Level `Enum` definition for `cls` field**

```
class Level(Enum):
    V = 'V'
    VI = 'VI'
    VII = 'VII'
    VIII = 'VIII'
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29704741/6560549), but the basic pattern is to override `Form.validate()` with `AddStudentForm.validate()`, first call  `super().validate()` to validate the individual fields, and if they pass, then test the uniqueness of the two combined fields.

Comment: Super thanks to you. That's exactly what I needed. It's working for me. One other thing. Instead adding error msg to individual fields is there any form level error field to add error msg.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, however, you could either append a message to the individual fields errors `self.cls.errors.append("informative error message")`, or use `from flask import flash` [and flash a message](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/) before returning from the validator.

Comment: That's what I thought. Anyway it seems now adding field wise error message is the better option. Thanks for you help though.